# Passing value from one form to another doesnt work

Tags: c#, forms, label

This is my C# ADO.NET app. I am trying to pass name and surname of my logged user from my LoginForm to my MainMenuForm. I  have property for that, but it doesnt work. LoggedPerson is person from my database. Pls help me... 
here is my code:

LoginForm code:

```
public string TheName
    {
        get { return this.LoggedPerson.Name + " " + LoggedPerson.Surname; }

    }
```

MainMenuForm:

```
public MainMenu()
    {
        LoginForm nova = new LoginForm();
        this.MenuLabelLoggedPerson.Text = nova.TheName;
        InitializeComponent();

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to change your code like this:

```
public MainMenu()
{       
    InitializeComponent();
    LoginForm nova = new LoginForm();
    this.MenuLabelLoggedPerson.Text = nova.TheName;
}
```

The `InitializeComponent` is visual studio generated code when you drag and drop in Windows Forms.

**EDIT**

Your problem is you create the new `LoginForm`, but you don't set `TheName` property.

Comment: Now I dont get error message but my label's text is not changed. Should I write all my code in question ?

Comment: Yes I have. And as I said in previous comment, I dont get error message anymore, but my label's text is not changed. :/

Comment: I am total newbie to C# and this may be stupid question, but why I need to make set block in my property when I only need to GET name and surname of logged person, and not to SET it ?

Comment: If you don't SET it, where the value come from?

Comment: I think u don't understand me... Name and surname of my logged person is already in my LoggedPerson variable which is in my LoginForm, and I just need to pass that name and surname to my MainMenuForm by using get property. I don't need to set that, I just want that name and surname of my logged person displays in my label which is in my MainMenuForm. That's all... I may be stupid, but I have read your answer 6 times, and still dont see point in SET property. Even if I make SET property, label doesnt display name and surname of logged person...

Comment: Maybe problem is that I am closing my LoginForm when login is succesful ?

Comment: Can you print the Name and surname? what is the value